# Error handing and flow within private methods on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Reviewing a coworker's PR I came across a pattern I have not seen before, where a private method was called and `or return` appended to the end if that method failed. I [found a blog post mentioning this (number 2)](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/) but it feels strange to me.

The code sort of looks like this:

```
class OurController < ApplicationController
  def index
    amount = BigDecimal.new(params[:amount]).to_i

    if amount < 0
      cancel_processing(amount) or return
    else
      process(amount)
    end

    render json: {success: true}
  end

  private

  def cancel_processing(amount)
    response = CancelProcessingService.call(amount)

    if response
      log_stuff
    else
      render json: {error: true} and return
    end
  end
end
```

Since the render error is being called from within the method, it's not ending, and it's therefore going to the end of the `index` action and double rendering (without the `or render` after `cancel_processing`).

This feels like a smell to me. `render`s and `return`s are respected within before_filters, so them not being respected in methods feels inconsistent. Maybe it just feels wrong because I haven't encountered this `or return` pattern before, but I ask: **is there a way to get Rails to respect `render... and return`s from within methods** (which are not before_filters or actions)?

I feel like advocating for rewriting these methods to simply return JSON, and pass the response to render later on in the method -- but if this is a normal pattern then I have no ground to suggest that.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: `or return` always seemed like a like a Perl-ism to me... That being said, this sounds like a very opinionated question...

Answer (score 3):

`render ... and/or return` is a bogus pattern. Rails documentation uses it in a couple of places but I believe it should not. It's bogus because although `render` returns a truthy value (the rendered response body) when it succeeds, when it fails it does not return a falsy value but raises an error. So there is no point in handling the nonexistent case when it returns a falsy value. (The same applies to `redirect_to`.)

In an action, to avoid misleading anyone about how `render` works, just do

```
render # options
return
```

to render and then exit.

In a private method called by an action, you can't say `return` and exit from the calling action, because Ruby methods don't work that way. Instead, make the method return a value that the action can interpret and return early if appropriate. Something like this:

```
def index
  amount = BigDecimal.new(params[:amount]).to_i
  if amount < 0
    if !cancel_processing(amount)
      return
    end
  else
    process(amount)
  end
  render json: {success: true}
end

def cancel_processing(amount)
  response = CancelProcessingService.call(amount)
  if response
    log_stuff
  else
    render json: {error: true}
  end
  response
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a controller you can call [performed?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-performed-3F) to find out if a render/redirect has already been called. For example:

```
performed? # => false
render json: {error: true}
performed? # => true
```